# Deck of cards, Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault

I've been writing a program that populates a deck of cards. I'm using a makefile to build the executable but keep getting a segmentation fault when I execute. Can someone please take a look at the code below and point out where the error is coming from?

Thanks!

Card.h

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H
#include <iostream>

class Card
{
public:
        Card(char rankSet, char suitSet);
        Card();
private:
        char rank, suit;
};
#endif
```

Card.cpp

```
#include "Card.h"

Card::Card()
{
        rank = 'A';
        suit = 'C';
}

Card::Card(char rankSet, char suitSet)
{
        rank = rankSet;
        suit = suitSet;
}
```

Deck.h

```
#ifndef DECK_H
#define DECK_H
#include <iostream>
#include "Card.h"

class Deck
{
public:
        Deck();
private:
        Card *deckOfCards;
};
#endif
```

Deck.cpp

```
#include "Deck.h"

Deck::Deck()
{
        char ranks[13] = {'A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K'};
        char suits[4] = {'C','D','H','S'};

        deckOfCards = new Card[52];
        int k = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<13; i++)
        {
                for(int j=0; j<4; i++)
                {
                        deckOfCards[k] = Card(ranks[i],suits[j]);
                        k++;
                }
        }
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Deck.h"

int main()
{
        Deck deck1;
        return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
#

CC = g++
CFLAGS  = -g -Wall -lm

#
default: Main

# To create the executable file count we need the object files

Main:  Main.o Card.o Deck.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o Main main.o Card.o Deck.o

# To create the object file
Main.o:  main.cpp Deck.h Card.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.cpp

# To create the object file
Deck.o:  Deck.cpp Deck.h Card.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c Deck.cpp

# To create the object file
Card.o:  Card.cpp Card.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c Card.cpp


clean:
    $(RM) Main *.o *~
```

Comment: `for(int j=0; j<4; i++)` <== last term. I assume that's a typo in your code, not your question.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the makefile (as you could have verified by building without it). I'm removing the `makefile` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You increment i instead of j inside the for loop